# Classloader being called before missingProperty

Tags: gradle, groovy

Let's say I have a script called `Utils.groovy`:

```
package hello

def testMethod() {
    log.info("hello world")
}

def propertyMissing(String name) {
    System.out.println("Loading ${name}.groovy")
    GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine("vars")
    gse.loadScriptByName("${name}.groovy").newInstance()
}
```

It makes a reference to a property which doesn't exist, `log`. However `log` exists as a class that will be loaded by the Groovy script engine:

```
void info(Object message) {
    println(message)
}
```

If `Utils.groovy` itself is loaded by the GroovyScriptEngine, it will call the `propertyMissing` method and dynamically load `log.groovy`.

Here is the example code that loads `Utils.groovy`:

```
package hello

class Main {
    static void main(String... args) {
        GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine("src")
        Class<Script> scriptClass = gse.loadScriptByName("hello/Utils.groovy")
        def utils = scriptClass.newInstance()

        //def utils = new Utils()

        utils.testMethod()
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Loading log.groovy
hello world
```

Now, instead of being loaded by the GSE, let's instantiate a new instance of `Utils.groovy` and execute it directly (by commenting out the first three lines in the above example and uncommenting the next line):

```
package hello

class Main {
    static void main(String... args) {
        //GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine("src")
        //Class<Script> scriptClass = gse.loadScriptByName("hello/Utils.groovy")
        //def utils = scriptClass.newInstance()

        def utils = new Utils()

        utils.testMethod()
    }
}
```

However, it fails to call the `propertyMissing` method on Utils.groovy and instead attempts to load `log.groovy` directly from the classpath. However. since `info` isn't a static method, if fails with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static log.info() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hello world]
Possible solutions: info(java.lang.Object), find(), any(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), is(java.lang.Object), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1518)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1504)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at hello.Utils.testMethod(Utils.groovy:4)
    at hello.Utils$testMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at hello.Main.main(Main.groovy:11)
```

However. I noticed that if I change the name of the `log` property to something that doesn't exist on the classpath (`loggy.info` for example, and kept the `log.groovy` filename the same), it *does* end up calling the `propertyMissing` method (but fails because it can't find the non-existant script):

```
Loading loggy.groovy
Exception in thread "main" groovy.util.ResourceException: Cannot open URL: file:/home/wlaw/test/vars/loggy.groovy
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.getResourceConnection(GroovyScriptEngine.java:408)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.loadScriptByName(GroovyScriptEngine.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:213)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at hello.Utils.propertyMissing(Utils.groovy:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:890)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1854)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3773)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.getProperty(GroovyObjectSupport.java:38)
    at groovy.lang.Script.getProperty(Script.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:310)
    at hello.Utils.testMethod(Utils.groovy:4)
    at hello.Utils$testMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at hello.Main.main(Main.groovy:11)
```

So it looks like the `propertyMissing` method will only be called if 1. the script is instantiated directly and it refers to a missing property whose name is *not* on the classpath or 2. the script is loaded by the GSE.

So my question is, is there a reason why Groovy attempts to locate a class first instead of calling `propertyMissing` for objects not loaded by the GSE? And is there a way I can change this behavior?

Note: both `vars` and `src` are in the classpath of the project.
Also note: I am running these files by first running them through `groovyc` and then with `java`.

Comment: it's quite logical if there is a class with name log in classpath. java/groovy tries to load this class.

Comment: i mean classloader always goes before propertyMissing. in one case you don't log class in classpath. in case of error there is a class log in your classpath.

Comment: Not necessarily. The classloader only goes first for classes that are instantiated directly. If it is loaded by the GSE, propertyMissing goes first.

Comment: If you try `String.format()` - you are not instantiating it - how groovy should decide that String is a class and not a property? I believe classloader always goes first.

Comment: I am talking about the lines in Main.groovy. If an object is instantiated directly (`def utils = new Utils()`) then it's `propertyMissing` method is not called first for missing properties that match the name of a class on the classpath. If an object is instantiated through the GSE, its propertyMissing` method _is_ called first. That's nice that you "believe" the classloader goes first, but my example shows otherwise.

Comment: Remove log class from classpath and missing property will be called first.

Comment: Thanks for telling me something I already know. But that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: look, i put `Main.groovy` and `Utils.groovy` into `.\hello` folder, `log.groovy` into `.\vars` folder and starting it with command: `groovy -cp . hello\Main.groovy` and everything works fine for both cases of Utils instantiation. i just want to say that error you have depends on how you starting the project and if class `log` pre-loaded by any parent/root classloader.

Comment: Right, but if i compile the script using `groovyc --sourcepath=./src log.groovy hello/Main.groovy hello/Utils.groovy -d=../out` and then run it with Java: `java -cp ../groovy-all-2.4.20.jar:. hello.Main`, I get the same MissingMethodException as I did earlier.

Comment: why you are compiling `log.groovy` when you are using GroovyScriptEngine for it? with groovy script engine you are parsing script at runtime in any case, and storing compiled `log.class` into classpath just fails your idea.

Comment: Because this is a watered down example to make a point. Gradle uses `groovyc` to compile source code before tests are run, so I am doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "log" is a type it will be resolved as such during compilation. If you want "log.info(...)" to always try for a dynamic property, you can write "this.log.info(...)". Groovy lets you write class literals shorter, so "log" is interpreted as "log.class", which explains the static method search for "info".